# Passing a 2D char array in C to a function

Tags: c

Why can't I pass a 2D char array in C to a function as

```
int .....(char array[ ][ ])
```

i.e with the square brackets empty?

That works with 1D arrays, but I don't understand why it doesn't work with 2d arrays

Comment: i think your compiler gives you some suggestions about it

Comment: online gcc compiler gives error about incomplete type of char[][]. you should pay attention to compiler errors.

Comment: Change `char array[][]` to `char** array` and it will work fine.

Comment: what does char ** actually mean @Whatever

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the called function needs to know about the size of the array in order to access the elements.

When you do

```
int arr[7][5] = {0};

arr[3][2] = 42;
```

the access is really

```
*(arr + 3*5 + 2) = 42;
          ^
          note: the number of columns
```

So in order to access elements in a 2D array the function **must** have information about the number of columns.

Therefore is

```
int foo(char array[ ][ ]) { array[3][2] = 42; }
```

**not valid** C code. The function simply can't know how to access `array[3][2]`

But you can do

```
void foo(char array[][10])
```

and

```
void foo(int c, char array[][c])
```

because in both cases `foo` gets the informantion it needs to access the array elements.

You can extend this to arrays of higher dimensions, i.e. the function needs to know the size of all dimensions except the first. Example:

```
void foo(char array[][42][10])
```

Comment: The last example works only if the compiler supports VLA, so don't take it for granted. I think you should include in your answer that the compiler requires size information for all (regardless of how many there are) but the first dimension, i.e. `int arr[][4][5]`.

Answer (score 0):

*That works with 1D arrays ?* Because in that case in function argument `char array[ ]` is not a `array`, it's a `pointer`. And apart from passing `array name` you are passing array `size` also to the function, so that you can rotate loop `size` times. Here is the simple demo of passing 1D array to function

```
void pass(int new_arr[],int ele) { /* here new_arr is not an array, it a pointer
*/
        /* here this pass() should know how many elements new_arr holds,
                that's why second argument is no of element */
}
int main(void) {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int ele = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        pass(arr,ele);/* you are arr, means 1D array base address and no of elements */
        return 0;
}
```

*Why can't I pass a 2D char array in C to a function as `int .....(char array[ ][ ])` ?*  Lets look at compiler warning when you tried this

```
void pass(int new_arr[][],int row) {
}
```

it says

> array type has incomplete element type

So when you pass `2D` array to a function like

```
int arr[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
pass(arr,row);/* passing 2D array base address to function and you need to inform no of rows to function */
```

you are just passing `2D` array name i.e base address, how that function will come to know whether you passed `1D` array address or `2D` array address. you(calling function) need to tell to called function that this `2D` array contains this many `1D` array.

So when you are passing `2D` array to a function, called function argument should be of type of *pointer to an array* like `char(*)[row]` not with `char**` or `char[][]`. for e.g

```
void pass(int (*new_arr)[3],int row) { /* here new_arr points to 3 elements at a time i.e in each 1D array contains 3 elements*/

}
```